3 tikzpictures into 1 preserving coordinates
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} \usepackage[english,greek]{babel} \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc} \usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,snakes}
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=1]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 



\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\node [] at(0,5){    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{spring}=[double,decorate,decoration={pre=lineto,pre length=0.3cm, ,post=curveto,post length=0.3cm,aspect=0, segment length=1mm, amplitude=2.2mm,coil}]
\tikzstyle{platform1}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.3cm]
\coordinate (topspring) at (0,0);
\coordinate (bottomspring) at (0,-2cm);
\draw [spring] (bottomspring) -- (topspring) node[draw=none,pos=.5,left=.25cm] (spring){$k$};

\draw[thick,-](-1,0)--(1,0);

\node [platform1,anchor=south] at (0,0)  {};

\end{tikzpicture}};\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{spring}=[double,decorate,decoration={pre=lineto,pre length=0.3cm, ,post=curveto,post length=0.3cm,aspect=0, segment length=2mm, amplitude=2.2mm,coil}]
\tikzstyle{platform1}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.3cm]
\coordinate (topspring) at (0,0);
\coordinate (bottomspring) at (0,-4cm);
\draw [spring] (bottomspring) -- (topspring) node[draw=none,pos=.5,left=.25cm] (spring){$k$};

\draw[thick,-](-1,0)--(1,0);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!40,rounded corners] (-0.4,-4) rectangle (0.4,-4.7)node at (0,-4.35)[font=\small]{$m_1$};
\node [platform1,anchor=south] at (0,0)  {};
\shade[ball color=white] (0,-5.5) circle (0.25)node at (0,-5.5)[font=\small]{$m$};
\draw[thick,-stealth'](0.4,-5.8)--(0.4,-5.2)node[right,pos=0.5][font=\small]{$\vec v_2$};
\draw[thick,-stealth',violet](1,-1)--(1,-2)node[right,pos=0.5][font=\small]{$(+)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{spring}=[double,decorate,decoration={pre=lineto,pre length=0.3cm, ,post=curveto,post length=0.3cm,aspect=0, segment length=2mm, amplitude=2.2mm,coil}]
\tikzstyle{platform1}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.3cm]
\coordinate (topspring) at (0,0);
\coordinate (bottomspring) at (0,-4cm);
\draw [spring] (bottomspring) -- (topspring) node[draw=none,pos=.5,left=.25cm] (spring){$k$};

\draw[thick,-](-1,0)--(1,0);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!40,rounded corners] (-0.4,-4) rectangle (0.4,-4.7);
\node [platform1,anchor=south] at (0,0)  {};
\shade[ball color=white] (0,-4.35) circle (0.25);
\draw[thick,-stealth'](0.55,-4.5)--(0.55,-3.8)node[right,pos=0.5][font=\small]{$\vec v_{\kappa}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{document}



Welcome. // You certainly do not need to include an armarda of packages for this problem. Please comment out, what isn‘t needed. Thank you

I want the three platforms to be in the same height, i uploaded a picture.

Do not nest tikzpictures, rather use the fit library. You load libraries multiple times, this is not necessary. Consider tidying up your code a bit. Apart from that (but probably unrelated to your question): tikz-feynman makes use of Lua, so it is best to be used with LuaLaTeX if you want to make use of all its functions; and when loading pgfplots you should always set \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} (or similar) to make use of all recent features of this package.

To align the three tikzpictures at their relevant top, replace \begin{tikzpicture} with \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(topspring)}] for all three instances. This way, you set the baseline of the three tikzpictures to where the coordinate (topspring) sits. This is probably what you want.

Yes, yes...thanks a lot...fantastic. Thanks a lot Jasper for your quick answer. Although a teacher, i feel like a student inside here. And you are also right about my code.

Please note that \tikzstyle is obsolete. Have a look in the manual for \tikzset

You still should take care about the code you post. 1)  2) You probably won't need more than 5 of the listed packages AND libraries. Throwing everything out - without some careful preparation - puts unecessary extra-effort to each one of us, trying to help you. // Please try better next time. Thank you

Can you take the time to edit your post to add a question?  Comments are never guaranteed to not be moved or deleted

The main part of the solution is to use baseline={(topspring)} as option to all three tikzpictures to align them to the same coordinate.
But, you should also do some other things:

Do not nest tikzpictures. It is not supported and not necessary in this case.
Use \tikzset instead of \tikzstyle, The latter is deprecated. Also, since you reuse a few styles, you could define \tikzset outside the scope and just change the relevant styles as needed.
Remove all unnecessary libraries and packages, try not to load things multiple times and think about which packages already load things (for example, pgfplots loads tikz and tikz loads xcolor).

A minimal working example of the above would be:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows}

\tikzset{
    spring/.style={
        double,
        decorate,
        decoration={
            pre=lineto,
            pre length=0.3cm,
            post=curveto,
            post length=0.3cm,
            aspect=0, 
            segment length=1mm, 
            amplitude=2.2mm,
            coil
        }
    },
    platform1/.style={
        fill,
        pattern=north east lines,
        draw=none,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=0.3cm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(topspring)}]

    \coordinate (topspring) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (bottomspring) at (0,-2cm);
    \draw [spring] (bottomspring) -- (topspring) 
        node[draw=none, pos=.5, left=.25cm] (spring) {$k$};
    \draw[thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \node[platform1, anchor=south] at (0,0)  {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(topspring)}, spring/.append style={segment length=2mm}]

    \coordinate (topspring) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (bottomspring) at (0,-4cm);
    \draw [spring] (bottomspring) -- (topspring) 
        node[draw=none, pos=.5, left=.25cm] (spring) {$k$};
    \draw[thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[thick, fill=gray!40, rounded corners] (-0.4,-4) rectangle (0.4,-4.7)
        node at (0,-4.35) [font=\small] {$m_1$};
    \node[platform1, anchor=south] at (0,0) {};
    \shade[ball color=white] (0,-5.5) circle (0.25)
        node at (0,-5.5) [font=\small] {$m$};
    \draw[thick, -stealth'] (0.4,-5.8) -- (0.4,-5.2)
        node[right, pos=0.5, font=\small] {$\vec v_2$};
    \draw[thick, -stealth', violet] (1,-1) -- (1,-2)
        node[right, pos=0.5, font=\small] {$(+)$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(topspring)}, spring/.append style={segment length=2mm}]

    \coordinate (topspring) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (bottomspring) at (0,-4cm);
    \draw [spring] (bottomspring) -- (topspring) 
        node[draw=none, pos=.5, left=.25cm] (spring) {$k$};
    \draw[thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[thick, fill=gray!40, rounded corners] (-0.4,-4) rectangle (0.4,-4.7);
    \node[platform1, anchor=south] at (0,0) {};
    \shade[ball color=white] (0,-4.35) circle (0.25);
    \draw[thick, -stealth'] (0.55,-4.5) -- (0.55,-3.8)
        node[right, pos=0.5, font=\small] {$\vec v_{\kappa}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}


